# Envers auditing @Embedded and use targetAuditMode NOT_AUDITED

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-envers, auditing

I'm trying to add envers auditing to a model which has some @Embedded elements. Those elements themselves are not audited.

On a regular relation field to achieve this, you would write `@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)`.

However, this seems not to work on the @Embedded entry. At runtime, I still get error:
*Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An audited relation from XX to a not audited entity Building! Such mapping is possible, but has to be explicitly defined using @Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED).*

```
 @Embedded
 @AttributeOverrides({
   @AttributeOverride(name = "building"),
   @AttributeOverride(name = "division"))
 })
 @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED) // doesn't work
 private BuildingInfo buildingInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working - the *targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED* should be added to the *building* and *division* properties inside the BuildingInfo model.

In the model I want to audit:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
   @AttributeOverride(name = "building"),
   @AttributeOverride(name = "division"))
 })
 @Audited
 private BuildingInfo buildingInfo;
```

And in the BuildingInfo model:

```
@Embeddable
public class BuildingInfo implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private Buidling building;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private Division division;
}
```